# Order of blessing children on Erev Shabbos

Tags: minhag, blessing, children-parenting, leil-shabbat

When blessing children on erev Shabbos, is there a correct or preferred order (oldest to youngest, boys first or girls), or may parents decide however they like? If there is not a correct order, can it vary from week to week or should it be consistent?

Comment: nice question! the basis is bereshit 48:20, so maybe youngest first? :) http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0148.htm וַיְבָרְכֵם בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא, לֵאמוֹר, בְּךָ יְבָרֵךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל לֵאמֹר, יְשִׂמְךָ אֱלֹהִים כְּאֶפְרַיִם וְכִמְנַשֶּׁה; וַיָּשֶׂם אֶת-אֶפְרַיִם, לִפְנֵי מְנַשֶּׁה

Comment: but how did your parents do it? this is surely something in the realm of minhag...

Answer (score 5):

Although perhaps there is a Sefer that discusses this, I am not aware of it. However my father  would go in order of age, oldest to youngest, first all the boys and then all the girls. My father in law would do it in order of age, oldest to youngest mixing the boys and girls. So I guess there are at least 2 different ways that people do it.